# Aero Effect disables automatically

Tags: windows-7, themes, aero

Some months ago I have my windows 7 aero effect enabled, and there is no problem. But now I have problems when using aero effect (I mean aero theme).

1. First when using aero theme, minimizing windows take a long time,
   windows halt for some seconds like 7 or 10.
2. The second problem is after minimizing windows(sometimes), my
   windows automatically change into classic theme and show me a
   message saying "The memory is not enough, to boost performance
   switched to classic theme", even though I have 4 GB ram installed
   and no extensive CPU usage.

This happen no matter whether applications are opened or not. But I created a new user account and found out that the new account is working perfectly well in aero theme. I don't know why. And in that new account **ALL SHORTCUTS** didn't load the graphics, just the white spaces. Please give me solutions.

Comment: Silly solution, but did you check for viruses? There are seriously some viruses which just like tease the user with such kind of anoying things.

Comment: What sort of graphics hardware do you have?

Comment: @Karan Graphic Card is ATI RAdeon HD 4330 512 MB.

Comment: Type "adjust perf" in the Start Menu search and press Enter. Have you changed any of the settings on the Visual Effects tab? If so, try resetting back to defaults. Also try sfc /scannow (see http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/sfc-scannow.htm for help), and make sure your graphics driver is up to date.

Comment: @Karan I don't think that is the problem with visual effects tab, though i use to change it by tune up utilities. Also if it is system file problem there should also be problem in the new account, but it worked **perfectly**.

Comment: If it's not a corrupted file, it must be a corrupted/incorrect setting that the new account 'fixes' by setting to defaults. In any case, given how often I've seen people messing up their systems by using these so-called system 'optimizers', I won't even hazard to guess what TuneUp Utilities might have done to cause this. Why don't you use the new account instead, and try rebuilding the icon cache (see http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html for help), which will hopefully fix the missing shortcut icons issue?